# compare and calculate numbers in array to get close to a target

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have an array with 3

I want to combine them in order to get as close to 1000 as possible, but if one of the numbers would be 1000 then of course I want to just take that number.

If the program finds a combination that is equally close to 1000, maybe 999 and 1001, it should take the highest number.

I have two problems in my code:

1) if one number is 1000, it does not answer 1000. it answers 1000 and the other lowest number.

2) it finds the best match depending on in which order I give the input numbers. It should find it regardless.

Example: My input is `900, 500, 498 and 4`.This gives me `904`, which is wrong.

My input is `2, 498, 900 and 500`. The output is `1002`, which is correct.
Same numbers but in different order:

> Example: my input is `4, 5, 6, 1000`. It gives me 1004, but it should give me 1000.

Here is my code

remember: it is AT LEAST 3 `Integer` in the array already!

```
        int target = 1000;
        int optimum = 0;
        int optimum_distance = target;
        List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
        sums.add(0,weights[0]);

try {
    for(int i=1; i < weights.length; i++) {
        int weight = weights[i];
        List<Integer> newSums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j=0; j < sums.size(); j++) {

            int sum = sums.get(j);
                newSums.add(sum);
                int newSum = sum + weight;
                int distance = Math.abs(target - newSum);
                if (newSum <= target) {
                    newSums.add(newSum);
                    if (distance < optimum_distance) {
                        optimum = newSum;
                        optimum_distance = distance;
                    }
                }
                else if (distance < optimum_distance || (distance == optimum_distance && newSum > optimum))
                {
                    optimum = newSum;
                    optimum_distance = distance;
                    newSums.add(newSum);
                }
            }
        sums = newSums;
    }
} catch (Exception e){
  System.err.println("Error");
  System.exit(1);
}
System.out.print(optimum);
```

Comment: Well, your algorithm is completely unsuitable for what you want. For getting the optimal solution, you'd have to use recursion. This will mean it won't be suitable for large inputs, since this is an NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be not exactly what you are looking for, but solves the requierments.
The approach is to build a powerset and calculate their sum. The powerset of {1, 2, 3} is:

{{},{1}, {2}, {3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}

```
public class CloseTo1000 { 
static Set<List<Integer>> powerSet = new HashSet<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {        

    List<Integer> mainList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mainList.add(900);
    mainList.add(500);
    mainList.add(498);
    mainList.add(4);
    powerSet = buildPowerSet(mainList,mainList.size());
    System.out.println(powerSet);

    Set<List<Integer>> toremove = new HashSet<List<Integer>>(); //remove the empty set
    for(List<Integer> li : powerSet){
        if(li.isEmpty()){
        toremove.add(li);
        }
    }
    powerSet.removeAll(toremove);

    findOptimum(powerSet);        
}

private static Set<List<Integer>> buildPowerSet(List<Integer> list, int count){

    powerSet.add(list);

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        temp.remove(i);
        buildPowerSet(temp, temp.size());
    }
    return powerSet;
}


private static int findOptimum(Set<List<Integer>> powerSet){
    int opt = 10000 ;
    List<Integer> optList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (List<Integer> li : powerSet){
        int k = Math.abs(li.stream().mapToInt(Integer :: intValue).sum()-1000);// find absolute difference to 1000
        System.out.println(k);   
        if(k<opt){
        opt=k;
        optList=li;
        }
        if(k==opt && li.stream().mapToInt(Integer :: intValue).sum()>1000){// 999 and 1001, it should take the highest number
        opt=k;
        optList=li;
        }
    } 
    opt = opt +1000;
     System.out.println("optList: "+optList);
     System.out.println("opt: " +opt);
    return opt;     
}
}
```